# My Ubuntu won't shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

When I try to shutdown my Ubuntu 16.04 system, the screen goes black and it's pretty much shut down, except for the fact that the power button keeps being lit. That means that the laptop hasn't shutdown completely yet and I have to keep holding the power button for the laptop to shut down completely.

How do I fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is related to ACPI not working as it should.
Try enforcing the power interface as a boot option to see if this fixes it.

First open a terminal and try

```
sudo update-grub
sudo init 0
```

and see if it turns off properly (i'm guessing it won't, but just to make sure).

If it does not, reboot, when grub appears press **e**, this should show your boot parameters

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=<something-something> quiet splash
```

add acpi=force to it

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=<something-something> quiet splash acpi=force
```

hit enter to boot, now try to shut it down again and see if it turns off.

*If it does*, you can make this option permanent by editing the grub config.

Make a backup of your current grub.cfg (just in case)

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup
```

Now open the file in an editor, like

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And search for

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and change it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

save it, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and try shutting down again. This is the same as before, but permanently added, if you want to go back/restore your backup, remember to run **update-grub** again, after changing the config.

Comment: Did everything you said but it didn't work but thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - instead of shutting down or restarting, Ubuntu would just freeze - and it was fixed by downgrading kernel from 4.13. to 4.9.

I have a brand new Asus VivoBook Pro with freshly installed Win 10 + Ubuntu 16.04